# How to Trigger an aws lambda every 5th and 5+1th minute

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, aws-event-bridge

I am new to aws and trying to figure out a problem. I have to create a lambda which should get triggered every 5th and (5+1)th minute.

I m using event bridge and have create two rules. First one works fine but second rule doesn't. Please find some sample code below. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
Rule.Builder.create(stack.getStack(), id + "QueueEventsRuleN")
        .ruleName("my-rule-n-" + stack.getParameter(EParameter.APP_NAME).getValueAsString()
                + "-" + stack.getParameter(EParameter.TARGET_ENVIRONMENT).getValueAsString() + "-cdk" + stack.getDeploymentSuffix())
        .description("schedule events to trigger Lambda every "+n+" minutes")
        .schedule(Schedule.expression("rate("+n+" minutes)"))
        .targets(singletonList(LambdaFunction.Builder.create(function).build()))
        .build();

int scheduleTime = n+1;
Rule.Builder.create(stack.getStack(), id + "QueueEventsRuleNPlusOne")
        .ruleName("my-rule-n-plus-one" + stack.getParameter(EParameter.APP_NAME).getValueAsString()
                + "-" + stack.getParameter(EParameter.TARGET_ENVIRONMENT).getValueAsString() + "-cdk" + stack.getDeploymentSuffix())
        .description("schedule events to trigger Lambda every "+scheduleTime+" minutes")
        .schedule(Schedule.expression("rate("+scheduleTime+" minutes)"))
        .targets(singletonList(LambdaFunction.Builder.create(function).build()))
        .build();
```

Comment: " second rule doesnt" is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the question, you are able to create the rule successfully, the only issue is lambda not being triggered by the event bridge.

#### Lambda Permission (Triggers)

Check if the target lambda has permission to be triggered from the event bridge. by default, if you create a rule and add a target from the console, the AWS console takes care of adding lambda permissions for you. It can reviewed in *lambda console > lambda permission > settings > Triggers*

To add lambda permissions from AWS cli

```
aws lambda add-permission \
      --function-name {your-lambda-function-name} \
      --statement-id {anything-random-alhanumeric} \
      --action 'lambda:InvokeFunction' \
      --principal events.amazonaws.com \
      --source-arn arn:aws:events:*:{aws-account-id}:rule/*.
```

replace {} info with actual data. It will allow lambda to be triggered from any rule in your AWS account.

Refer to the AWS docs, on an in-depth guide

> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eventbridge-lambda-not-triggered/